# CGaffine transform on UIView without transforming subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, transformation, cgaffinetransform

I have a subclass of a uiimageview with a button as a subview in it. I have added pinch gesture to apply a scaling affine transformation on the uiimageview, however i do not want the button (the subview) to also be scaled. Is there anyway to exclude the button from the transformation? As far as  i know the transformation transforms everything inside the view and all its subviews accordingly.

Comment: you cant, you have to take the other elements outside of that view, btw how did you manage to get a uibutton into an uiimageview? i believe the interface builder doesnt allow it

Comment: @LuisOscar yes it does not, maybe he did it by code, and yes he cannot achieve the behavior he listed in the question, he has to change the views arrangement to do that

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith just saying because based on his question and the others he asked hes probably applying the transformation to the view and not to the imageview.

Comment: @LuisOscar Its a subclass of uiimageview, so i just had a button inside that class and did [self addsubview:button] to put it onto the uiimageview.

Answer (score 3):

One way to hack it would be to add a category to UIView to apply the transformation to self while applying the inverse of the transformation* to all subviews.

*CGAffineTransformInvert will do what you want.

Comment: That works really well! In my case I had a transform to the view that does a scale and translate as follows:  ` let detailsViewGrow = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.3).translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: yMovement)`  Applying the invert to the subview makes the view's height increase and the subviews stay put. The good part is that they stay the same size (don't stretch). Bad part is they don't follow the top of the view to which they're anchored with AutoLayout so that will take some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Change the view heirarchy of your views, instead of having the `buttons` as children of the uiimageview, create a father `UIView` and add to it the `UIImageView` and the `UIButton`
Your new hierarchy would be like this

```
UIView -> UIImageView
       -> UIButton
```

the UIButton will be a sibling to UIImageView and not its child, now you can apply any transformation the `UIImageView` and it will not affect the `UIButton`

Comment: That is one way however I wanted to avoid having an extra UIView because the gesture recognizers will also interact with the UIView as well as the UIImageView and things start to get weird. Another way I tried was to remove the button when touches began, and then add it when touches ended, but still, the button seemed to get scaled. I assume that's because if you add a subview to a view that's been transformed so will the subview upon being added.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the transformation to the view layer instead

view.layer.transform = ...